# Is there a VisualStudio project template for native C++ Win32 services?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I know there is one for .NET based services, even one for managed C++, but I don't see one for native unmanaged C++ Win32 services. Anyone know of any 3rd party templates?

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a complete sample on msdn, consisting of four files:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540476%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just use the regular Win32 Console Application template.  A service doesn't have any special compile or link settings, just special code.  The SDK docs [mention this here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685477%28VS.85%29.aspx)